# Is it possible to have a bookmarks folder in Chrome that's synced across multiple user accounts?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks

I use different Chrome profiles (and user accounts) for work, but I often bookmark sites on my work profile that I'd really love to access on my personal profile without having to switch.

Is it possible to, say, have a synced bookmarks folder across multiple profiles like this? Or should I use another browser for this purpose (that maybe supports this functionality)?

Comment: You can have a universal profile with Chromium if you want';it will read and write Chrome-compatible profiles.